# Android: finish() refreshes the activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have activity A and B. Activity A calls B with the following codes:

```
Intent iSettings = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivityForResult(iSettings, ACTIVITY_SAVE_PREF);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
startActivity(iSettings);
```

Activity B finishes and go back to Activity A by pressing the BACK button which has the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putBooleanArray(KEY_PREFERENCES, value);

        Intent mIntent = new Intent();
        mIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntent);
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

My problem is that Activity B refreshes to its first state it was called by Activity A on the first `onKeyDown Back`. Activity B only finishes on the second `onKeyDown Back` and successfully returning to Activity A.

Could anyone help me and tell me if I'm missing something please?
Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: You're calling startActivity twice while going from A to B. Only once is required.

Comment: I see. That's so stu**d of me..LOL..I overlooked that one. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intent iSettings = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivityForResult(iSettings, ACTIVITY_SAVE_PREF); //here
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
startActivity(iSettings); // and here
```

Your starting your activity twice, so what you think is a refresh, is just you closing the second activity and the first one is behind it

Comment: Yeah. I overlooked that one..Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you avoid using two StartActivity...
only one is enough...because if called twice..one Activity behind another Actiivty...

Comment: Yeah. I overlooked that one..Thanks so much for helping!